# Sequence along numeric vector, increasing sequence only at trigger values

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, seq, cumsum

I have a `data.frame` ordered by ID with a column of numeric values that I would like to bin into groups, increasing the group number only when a certain target value/trigger is surpassed. I haven't had success with `seq()`, `seq_along()`, or `data.table` `cumsum()`, but I'm sure there must be a way

Example `data.frame` with desired group column below. In this example, the sequence generating the group column should increase *only* when a number >= 300 appears in the value column.

```
dat = data.frame(ID=1:10, value=c(0,2,1,12,68,300,41,0,72959,51), group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))

> dat
   ID value group
1   1     0     1
2   2     2     1
3   3     1     1
4   4    12     1
5   5    68     1
6   6   300     2
7   7    41     2
8   8     0     2
9   9 72959     3
10 10    51     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `cumsum` on a logical vector to create the group

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(group2 = cumsum(value >=300)+ 1)
```

-output

```
   ID value group group2
1   1     0     1      1
2   2     2     1      1
3   3     1     1      1
4   4    12     1      1
5   5    68     1      1
6   6   300     2      2
7   7    41     2      2
8   8     0     2      2
9   9 72959     3      3
10 10    51     3      3
```

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket. Thank you!